# Convert single key-value pair into multiples pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value, ecmascript-5

A script returns me an array containing the following key-value pair :

```javascript
[{"analytes":"ALBS,CRP,FR,FERHN"}]
```

How would you proceed in order to obtain multiple key-value pairs within an array, such as this one :

```javascript
[
  {"analyte":"ALBS"},
  {"analyte":"CRP"},
  {"analyte":"FR"},
  {"analyte":"FERHN"}
]
```

Plus, the program i am using is still using ECMAScript 5.

Comment: you'd split on `','` and `map` the result (I guess string has split and array has map in ES5) - though ... looking again, I can't see ANY similarity between input and output ... where do the values ALBU, CAU CLU CREAU GLUU KU NAU PHOSU Protéines urinaires UAU UREEU even come from? outer space? totally unrelated to input

Comment: I edited my post for clarity.

Comment: OK in that case it's a simple split + map as I said.. `input[0].analytes.split().map(analyte => ({analyte}))`

Comment: The program i am using being still stuck with ECMA5, i cannot use lambda expressions unfortunately.

Comment: Still, thank you for your advice, i will try to apply it to this earlier version of javascript.

Comment: There is a mistake in the comment answer.  It should be .split(",") with a comma. You can replace the arrow with a function to make it work.

Comment: I created my function as following :

`function Spliter(input) {
    
    input[0].analytes.split(",").map(analyte)
    
    return analyte
}`

but it triggers this error message : problem evaluating script: TypeError: Cannot read property "split" from undefined in at line number 53

Comment: `.map(analyte)          return analyte }` clearly not even ES5 ... sorry for confusing you with ES6 arrow notation, but that's so easy to fix - `input[0].analytes.split(",").map(function(analyte) { return {analyte:analyte})`

Comment: @yogi - somewhere in the deep recesses of my memory, I was convinced `split` with no argument split on `,` ... it's `join` of course that "defaults" to `,` - thanks for the pickup

Comment: It finally had it working on JSBIN with the following code :

`var input = [{"analytes":"ALBS,CRP,FR,FERHN"}]


function Spliter(list){
  
   return list[0].analytes.split(",").map(function(info){
           return {analyte:info} 
   
   })
   
  }



console.log(Spliter(input))`

... but not within the software i am using, which sends the following error :

_problem evaluating script: TypeError: Cannot read property "split" from undefined in at line number 52_

Really annoying, i would search help with the software developers.

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [string.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) along with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Demo **:**

```js
const jsonObj = [{"analytes":"ALBS,CRP,FR,FERHN"}];

const res = jsonObj[0].analytes.split(',').map(function(item) {
  return {"analyte": item}
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Yep, as i was saying in the comment, using a similar script from Bravo, and not using the => notation but function instead, i managed to have this working in JSBIN. But for an unknow reason, it does not work in the software i am using... 

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated code snippet.